# Automatic downcast of returned value using shared pointer in boost python

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I would like to know if there is a way to expose a "downcasted" object as a result of function in python using `boost::python`, while using shared pointers. Consider the following scenario:

```cpp
class A {
    virtual ~A() { }
};

class B: public A {
    std::shared_ptr<B> makeB() { return std::make_shared<B>(); }
    std::shared_ptr<A> f(bool b) { return b ? std::make_shared<B>() : std::make_shared<A>();
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module) {

    using namespace boost::python;

    register_ptr_to_python<std::shared_ptr<A>>();
    register_ptr_to_python<std::shared_ptr<B>>();

    class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>, boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init);

    class_<B, bases<A>, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
        .def("f", &B::f)
        .def("makeB", &B::makeB).staticmethod("makeB");

}
```

Now in python, I can retrieve a `B` object and call `f` but the resulting object will be seen as a `A` object:

```
import module

b = module.B.makeB()
type(b)  # This is module.B

u = b.f(true)
type(u)  # This is always module.A
```

Anyway to dynamically return an object of type `B` on the python side? In C++, I have to manually downcast, which is ok because it is common in C++, but in python I would appreciate a dynamic return type.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this working using a [result converter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/concepts/resultconverter.html#concepts.resultconverter.resultconverter_concept_requirem):

```
template <class FromType, class ToType>
struct DowncastReturn {

  template <class T>
  struct apply;

  template <>
  struct apply<std::shared_ptr<FromType>> {
    struct type {

      bool convertible() const { return true;  }

      inline PyObject* operator()(std::shared_ptr<FromType> p) const {
        if (p == nullptr) {
          return bpy::detail::none();
        }
        else {
          auto downcast_p = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ToType>(p);
          bpy::object p_value = downcast_p == nullptr ? bpy::object{ p } : bpy::object{ downcast_p };
          return bpy::incref(p_value.ptr());
        }
      }

      inline PyTypeObject const* get_pytype() const {
        return bpy::converter::registered_pytype<FromType>::get_pytype();
      }

    };
  };
};
```

Then this can be used:

```
class_<B, bases<A>, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
        .def("f", &B::f, return_value_policy<DowncastReturn<A, B>>())
        .def("makeB", &B::makeB).staticmethod("makeB");
```

This requires a bit more to setup than my first version but is much more easy to use if this is required for multiple methods.

---

#### First version:

This is the first version of my answer where I did the downcast manually without relying on a `return_value_policy`. The idea was simply to manually wrap the returned object into a `boost::python::object`:

```cpp
class_<B, bases<A>, boost::noncopyable>("B", no_init)
        .def("f", +[](B *self, bool b) { 
            auto *r = self->f();
            auto *rb = dynamic_cast<B*>(r);  
            return rb == nullptr ? object{ r } : object{ rb };
        })
        .def("makeB", &B::makeB).staticmethod("makeB");
```